# How can I access another variable I defined in another function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

The `Attack()` method will be used on a button and a want to define variables at the start but I'm not sure how to do it (Unity 2D):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.SearchService;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DefaultEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void DefineVariables()
    {
        int phealth = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().phealth;
        int pdamage = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().pdamage;

        int ehealth = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().ehealth;
    }

    public static void Attack()
    {
        ehealth = ehealth - pdamage
    }

    private void Update()
    {
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        DefineVariables();
    }
}
```

I've tried a few things like making a method for the variables. I expected this to do something but I just get a different error
:/

Comment: It's a **variable** - not a "varyable" :..

Comment: Why did you use static? What things have you tried? What did you expect to do? What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Unity, but your question has to do with variable SCOPE. Variables can be accessed from within the block that they're defined, so if you want to access variables from more than one method, they need to be defined outside the scope of a single method (at the class level):

```
public class DefaultEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Variables defined at the class level can 
    // be accessed from any method in the class
    int phealth = 0;
    int pdamage = 0;
    int ehealth = 0;

    public static void DefineVariables()
    {
        phealth = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().phealth;
        pdamage = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().pdamage;
        ehealth = GameObject.Find("VStorage").GetComponent<VStorage>().ehealth;
    }

    public static void Attack()
    {
        ehealth = ehealth - pdamage;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        DefineVariables();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating value in that script not the one in the `VStorage` component, to do that you want to use a reference to the `VStorage` component.

See the example below

```
// Reference to the VStorage component
private VStorage vStorage;

public static void Attack()
{
    //Update the value on the component like so
    vStorage.ehealth = vStorage.ehealth - vStorage.pdamage;
    //But it can be made simpler by using -= which does the same thing (+= will add a value)
    // vStorage.eHealth -= vStorage.pdamage;
}
private void Awake()
{
    // Setup the VStorage reference, you can find it using this method rather than looking for the GameObject and then getting the component
    vStorage = FindObjectOfType<VStorage>();
}
```

Take a look at these [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) on operators and expressions to better understand `-=`, etc

Comment: Now i just get an error saying an object refernce is required for the non static feild. Also the VStorage is a GameObject with a script attached to carry variables

Comment: You create the reference in the `Awake` method, thats what the `FindObjectOfType` is for

Comment: I still get the error but when io change the Awake() to Start() it workd fine :/